# How did the Gyptians bring a whole ship to the mulefa world?

Tags: his-dark-materials, the-amber-spyglass

I couldn't wait for the third season of *His Dark Materials* series so I read the whole trilogy.

My question is this: In *The Amber Spyglass*, how did the Gyptians bring a whole ship into the *mulefa* world from Lyra's world when the only established opening was a small opening from Cittàgazze and the opening from Lyra's world to Cittàgazze world is on top of a mountain?

Comment: Maybe they found a bigger one.

Comment: A bigger one not opened with the knife? Like the one opened by Lord Asriel which required a huge amount of energy such as the killing of Roger?

Comment: Yes, something like that. People in at least two worlds have separately figured out how two entirely different ways to open windows, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: As the angels (or is it a witch) later explain, there are all sorts of openings, not just the knife ones and Asriel's one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other openings exist. In the third novel, in particular, there is an event that causes massive damage to the "walls between the worlds":

> The Magisterium set a "bomb", which is targeted on Lyra with a lock of hair that Mrs Coulter has trimmed from Lyra. Although this bomb misses its target, it causes further massive rips between the worlds.

It is through one of these rips that the gyptians sail. It is also through these rips that the bears travel.